# continuation method return null from the continuation method it self instead of call back method return

Tags: lightning-aura-components, callout, continuation

```
public with sharing class ContinuationClass {


    // Action method
    @AuraEnabled(continuation=true cacheable=true)
    public static Object continuationCall() {
      // Create continuation. Argument is timeout in seconds.
      Continuation con = new Continuation(120);
      // Set callback method
      con.continuationMethod='callBackMethod';
      // Set state
      con.state='Hello, World!';
      // Create callout request
      HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
      req.setMethod('GET');
      req.setEndpoint(MY_ENDPOINT);
      con.addHttpRequest(req);
// Method is returning null from here while calling from lightning instead of returning from the callback response

      **return con;**  **// Actual return**
    }

    // Callback method ; This method is executing properly and i m getting the //response as well in my debug
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Object callBackMethod(List<String> labels, Object state) {
      // Get the response by using the unique label
      HttpResponse response = Continuation.getResponse(labels[0]);
      // Set the result variable
      String result = response.getBody();
      **return result;** // Expected return
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your endpoint is accessible directly ? also is it under remote site setting

Answer (score 0):

You will get 2 debug logs (in 2 transactions) for continuation. Consider below example:

```
@AuraEnabled(continuation=true cacheable=true)
public static Object startRequest() {
    Continuation con = new Continuation(40);
    con.continuationMethod='processResponse';
    con.state='Hello, World!';
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('GET');
    req.setEndpoint('callout:herokuAnimals');
    con.addHttpRequest(req);
    System.debug('con => '+con);
    return con;
}
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static Object processResponse(List<String> labels, Object state) {
    HttpResponse response = Continuation.getResponse(labels[0]);
    Map<String,Object> result = new Map<String,Object>();
    result.put('status', response.getStatus());
    result.put('body', JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody()));
    result.put('origin', 'continuation callout');
    System.debug('result => '+result);
    return result;
}
```

Here, the 2 debug logs (in 2 transactions) will be:

> 1. con => Continuation:[ContinuationMethod: processResponse, Timeout: 40]
> 2. result => {body={animals=(majestic badger, fluffy bunny, scary bear, chicken)}, origin=continuation callout, status=null}

In any case first method should return Continuation instance but in your example, the only reason I can think of why its returning null is because the endpoint may not be correct. Check that

1. `MY_ENDPOINT` refers to a string which starts with `callout:`
2. Check the endpoint mentioned above correctly in Named credentials - you do not need remote site settings if named credentials is configured

Comment: I got the answer. I tried to call my method from other Apex Class. Which will not call the callback method as i have trigger from apex instead of VF or Lightning. Check this for reference. https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005rguQAA